# Javascript function wont write to document

Tags: javascript

Why wont the function danDatuma write the array value uppon calling it? the console.log and alert work pefectly fine..
nothing shows up in console as error either

```js
function main() {
  danDatuma(new Date("2013-03-25T09:00:00-06:30"));
}

function danDatuma(datum) {
  var dnevi = ["Nedelja", "Ponedeljek", "Torek", "Sreda", "Četrtek", "Petek", "Sobota"];
  var indeksDneva = datum.getDay();
  //console.log(dnevi[indeksDneva]);
  //alert(dnevi[indeksDneva]);
  document.write(dnevi[indeksDneva] + "<br />");
}

main();
```

Comment: Where do you call `main()` ?

Comment: The code is actually working

Comment: I edited in a call to `main()` … and it worked. Whatever the problem is, it isn't exposed by the code you actually put in the question. You need to provide a real [mcve].

Comment: @PaulRooney — You don't. `document.write` after the document is closed will wipe out the existing document and replace it with the new content, but the OP says the new content isn't written so it doesn't sound like that is the problem.

Comment: @Quentin thanks never knew that. Things have probably changed since my web development heyday. Which was a while ago.

Comment: main is onload on body element in html..no need to worry about that